# SwiftUI: Can you animate a change in data itself, not just a view's response to the change?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

Is it possible to animate purely the change from value a to value b of a property, rather than just animating a view's response to the property's change?

For example, imagine tapping a button which increases a property by 10, though instead of the change being immediate, the app would update the property following a timing curve each time the view is rendered for the duration of the animation.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    
    @State private var exampleNumber: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print("New value is \(exampleNumber)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Number: \(exampleNumber)")
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    exampleNumber += 10.0
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Smoothly add 10")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

To be clear, it is the value of the original property I am looking to animate, not just the value displayed in a view. So on a 60fps device for instance, the "New value is..." print method would occur 60 times a second printing the new value which follows the `.easeInOut` timing curve.

This seems possible with `Animatable` or relatives but I cannot seem to get it to work yet. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoAnimatingNumber: View {
    @State private var number = Double.zero

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60)
            .modifier(AnimatingNumber(number: number))
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: number)
            .onTapGesture {
                number = number == Double.zero ? 10 : Double.zero
            }
    }
}

struct AnimatingNumber: AnimatableModifier {
    var number: Double

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { number }
        set { number = newValue }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(
            Text("Number: \(number, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking an age to get back. This is great and gets me half way there, but what I'm looking for is to be able to animate a change of state within the model, not in the view.

To explain, imagine an app which presents information directly dependant on a date (down to the second), stored in an environment object. A drag to the right progresses time, right rewinds etc. Using DragGesture's predictedEndTranslation, the date should animate to the new value.

It seems simple enough that I'm surprised of the lack of information on it, unless it's a SwiftUI limitation, achievable in UIKit?